# Vulnerabilty when running docker as non-root?

Tags: security, docker, dockerfile, user-permissions

I'm kind of fighting with privileges (no troll) for my Docker project as I'm trying to make one of my user on Docker, able to read/write a volume shared with the host, while the host user should also be able to read/write with the docker user in this directory.

In my case, nor Docker user, nor Host user should be root. This mean that, on the shared volume, the user which is running docker shouldn't be able to reach files in the volume that aren't. However, I discovered that running a volume as an user without root privileges do not save root's files

**Example**

For instance, in the following situation

*Users directory with two files, one root one non-root, the user's name is `user` and has no root privileges, however he is part of Docker group :*

```
C:/.../directory :
dwrx-rx--x root file1
dwrx-rx--x user file2
```

*Users run docker through the command :*

`docker run -v /c/.../directory:/volume:rw -e USER_ID=$(id -u) -e GROUP_ID=$(id -g)`

*And the entrypoint of Docker is the following `script.sh` :*

```
#!/bin/bash
usermod -u ${USER_ID} dockeruser \;
groupmod -g ${GROUP_ID} dockeruser ;
chown dockeruser:dockeruser -R /volume ;
exit;
```

*The permissions, even are changed on the host's directory, even for roots file that I shouldn't have been to write on :*

```
C:/.../directory :
dwrx-rx--x user file1
dwrx-rx--x user file2
```

Is it normal that, an user that isn't the root could do anything with files which do not belongs to him ?

I'm pretty a beginner so, I don't know if it's a misleading vulnerability due to the fact we force user to not be root nor sudo but in fact it doesn't change anything, or if I just am getting it wrong ^^, so feel free to tell me if it's not the way I should handle it.

Regards,
Waldo